# Parse comma separated string in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

Currently I'm trying this, which is printing out nothing (but there are no compilation problems):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void parseGprmc(char* gprmc) {
    printf("test");
    char* ptr;
    ptr = strtok(gprmc, ",");

    while(ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(gprmc, ",");
    }
}

int main() {
    char* gprmc = "$GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,,,E*62";

    printf("%s", gprmc);
    parseGprmc(gprmc);
    printf("%s", gprmc);

    return 1;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Ideally, `parseGprmc` would print out:

```
$GPRMC
081836
A
3751.65
S
14507.36
E
000.0
360.0


E*62
```

Considering the null values as valid as well but I don't think that `strtok` does that.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: `strtok()` changes its argument. In your case it's a *read-only* string (a pointer to a string literal) which makes `strtok()` fail (I'd have expected your program to abort with some kind of error). Try `char gprmc[] = "$GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,,,E*62";`

Comment: The second (and 3rd, 4th, ...) call to `strtok()` msut be passed NULL: `strtok(NULL, ",")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two serious issues in your code. First (as pointed out in the comments), the `strtok` function *modifies* the string given as its first argument – but you have declared `gprmc` as a pointer to a **constant** (immutable) string literal. To fix this, change the declaration to a `char` array that is initialized with a **copy** of the literal:

```c
    char gprmc[] = "$GPRMC,081836,A,3751.65,S,14507.36,E,000.0,360.0,,,E*62";
```

Second, only the *first* call to `strtok` for parsing a given string should have that string as its first argument; subsequent calls (on the *same* string) should use a `NULL` first argument (see [this cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), particularly the part beginning with *If str is not a null pointer, …*.

Here is a 'fixed' version of your `parseGprmc` function:

```c
void parseGprmc(char* gprmc)
{
    printf("test");
    char* ptr;
    ptr = strtok(gprmc, ","); // First call, use string address
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ","); // Subsequent calls, use NULL
    }
}
```

---

Note that it is not *directly* possible to extract empty (null) tokens using the `strtok` function, as the *function searches for the first character which is not contained in delim* (quoted from the same cppreference page). To do this, you have to add some 'tricks', comparing the returned address of each token with the address of the end of the previous token, and counting how many delimiter characters were in the 'gap'. Here is a possible modification of your function to do just that:

```c
void parseGprmc(char* gprmc)
{
    printf("test");
    char* ptr;
    char* lastend;
    ptrdiff_t nBlanks;
    ptr = strtok(gprmc, ","); // First call, use string address
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        lastend = ptr + strlen(ptr); // Address of last character in token
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, ","); // Subsequent calls, use NULL
        nBlanks = ptr ? ptr - lastend : -1; // Number of delimiters found
        while (--nBlanks >= 1) { // One empty token for each gap > 1
            printf("<null token>\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One remark about strtok is that you must use NULL for the second and next calls. This is because after the first call the contents of gprmc is modified and has an \0 in place of first ,

```
ptr = strtok(gprmc, ","); // for first call before the loop

ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");// for the call following in the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

homework?  inside the loop you don't pass `strtok` a pointer, you pass NULL. See help on that function.  But perhaps what you're wanting is to use `strchr` instead and change ',' to '\n' ?